# My latte-dock does not reappear after auto hiding

Tags: kubuntu, kde, autohide, latte-dock

I placed my latte dock panel on top of the screen with auto hide enabled. Once this panel auto hides it does not reappear back.

- My layout can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/hZ5heh83).
- Dock Version 9.86
- Kubuntu 20.10

Update(Tuesday, 8 December, 2020)

- Dock does not face this issue only panel does.
- placing the panel on left or right hand side does not solve the issue.

Comment: I don't use Kubuntu, so this may not help. I use Lubuntu and I use the existing panel tools to make my own dock. In this case, it's LXPanel, which won't help you. But, your existing panel (whatever that is for Kubuntu) may well allow you to create a new panel and then set that to behave as though it's a dock. I describe the process on **my site** [here](https://linuxtips.gq/2020/10/07/how-to-make-a-dock-in-lxpanel/). So, my advice is that maybe you can use that as your example and find the corresponding options in your own native panel software.

Answer (score 0):

launch latte dock with .

```
latte-dock --replace --cc
```

It will solve the issue